# How do I distribute a build to external testers via Fastlane?

Tags: fastlane, app-store-connect, fastlane-pilot

I have a Fastfile that performs the `uploadToTestFlight` action:

```
uploadToTestflight(
  username: "foo@example.com",
  skipWaitingForBuildProcessing: false,
  distributeExternal: true)
```

This succeeded when I ran it. However, it didn't actually distribute the build to anyone. When I look at the build on App Store Connect > My Apps > Foo App > TestFlight > iOS, it says "Approved" near the build name, which implies that it already went through the review process.

However, when I click on the build, I notice that the only groups or users to which it was released to is `App Store Connect Users`, meaning it wasn't actually externally released.

I have a group named `Foo Group` which I would like to release it to whenever I run fastlane. How do I do that?

I tried resolving via the [documentation for Pilot](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/pilot/) but it doesn't have an example with distributing externally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [Fastlane repo](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane) on GitHub, I found this code in `pilot/lib/pilot/build_manager.rb`

```
if options[:distribute_external] && options[:groups].nil?
  # Legacy Spaceship::TestFlight API used to have a `default_external_group` that would automatically
  # get selected but this no longer exists with Spaceship::ConnectAPI
  UI.user_error!("You must specify at least one group using the `:groups` option to distribute externally")
end
```

My guess is that you didn't notice this silent warning in the output of your Fastlane run. Did you specify the `groups` parameter?

Also it's worth to specify the `changelog` param if you're doing the external releases fully automatically.

Comment: Believe this is the correct answer. I’m confused by OP’s comment _This succeeded when I ran it._ though - if `groups` was unspecified then the command would fail, not succeed.

Comment: You should specify the group like `groups: ["Foo Group"]`

Comment: There is one issue with fastlane in this case. If that test group already exists, the tester will be added. If not, Fastlane will give the success message but that new group won't be created and the tester won't be added obviously. Any help here: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/16198

Answer (score 7):

```
optional_changelog = %Q{
  Your changelog
}

upload_to_testflight(
    ...
    changelog: optional_changelog,
    distribute_external: true,
    distribute_only: true, // false if you want to upload ipa
    groups: [
        "Your group",
        "Your other group"
    ],
    skip_submission: false, // defaults to false if not specified
    skip_waiting_for_build_processing: false, // defaults to false if not specified
)
```

Comment: This works?. I can't upload to External Groups my app

Comment: The console says I have to upload an Ipa. Is it possible to upload to External Groups without having to upload the IPA?

Comment: Try using `distribute_only: true`

Answer (score 2):

FTR I was having issues uploading to a external group and the issue is that `skip_waiting_for_build_processing` needs to be set to `false`.

So ensure that you have the follow params set

```
 distribute_external: true,
 groups: ['Name of your group'],
 skip_submission: true,
 notify_external_testers: true,
 skip_waiting_for_build_processing: false,
```

https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/testflight/#Parameters